# How to install Qt 5.x 32 bit on 64 bit ubuntu/debian?

Tags: software-installation, 32-bit, qt, debian

How to install Qt 32 bit and correctly build an application on 64 bit ubuntu/debian? Are there i686 or 32 bit packages like in SUSE? Which repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply install the same packages as for 64-bit, but append `:i386` onto the package name. For example, `libqt5webkit5:i386`. To compile against the libraries, you'll also need the appropriate i386 version of the appropriate -dev packages.

Comment: Where are they in debian? Add this info to Your answer please.

Comment: They should be the same in debian, assuming you are using a recent enough version of it, however questions about debian are off topic for this site. Only Ubuntu and official derivatives are on-topic.